# Is there an API to communicate with an embedded google sheet iframe i.e. to find out the current page?

Tags: javascript, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am embedding a google slides editor like this:

```
<iframe id="g" src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/(very long google key)/edit?rm=minimal" width="80%" height="700">
</iframe>
```

Is there a javascript API to communicate with this editor, i.e. to find out the current selected page and/or element?

I know about the [server based API](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/get) to maniuplate the content but here I am searching a way to communicate with the editor.

Comment: The short answer is NO. There is no js API to do that kind of web scraping. Depend on what you want to do [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) may be useful. But still backend API.

Comment: Not really trying to to web scraping. I want to embed own Google presentations into a a own web system and check on which page the current presentation is.